# No Menu in admin after Update to 2.4.4

Tags: upgrade, backend, admin-panel, magento2.4.4

Updated from 2.4.3 to 2.4.4, after updated PHP from 7.4 to 8.1. When logging into Magento Backend no submenus at the left panel or (for example) drop-downs for Store view appears.
`cache:flush`, `setup:upgrade`, `setup:di:compile`, `setup:static-content:deploy -f` does not help.

Edit:
Problem appears only in production mode, everything looks OK in Developer and Default mode.

Comment: acl issue to to the admin account permission may be ?

Comment: Maybe JS-minification:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35366

But in production mode problem appears again.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Quality-Patch MDVA-44887 was the solution: https://devdocs.magento.com/quality-patches/release-notes.html

Comment: Thank you for this answer. You saved me! Much appreciated.  Strange the error is only thrown in production mode. Thank you.